Как правильно написать: "Ты делал то, чего желал" или "Ты делал то, что желал"?
"Ты делал то, чего желал" или "Ты делал то, что желал"
Как более правильно?
Не могу определиться.
Заранее спасибо.

Я бы по слуху написала так: Ты делал то, что желал (делать).
Пояснение

Выбор действительно сложный. В обще случае мы выбираем между конкретным что (В.п.) и обобщенным  чего (Р.п.) по отношению к отвлеченным предметам. Поэтому в речи используются оба варианта.

Но выбор всегда индивидуален, и в каждом случае свое решение. Можно учесть  устойчивое выражение: Что хочу, то и делаю. Здесь пара: что — то, один и тот же падеж.  И обычный вопрос: Что ты делаешь (не чего).


Но вот что интересно: есть пример, где в одной статье используются оба варианта в одном тексте:
Делайте все, что хотите! Звучит заманчиво, правда? А что бы вы сделали, получив такое предложение? Почему-то в обществе принято считать, что если дать волю собственным желаниям, то мир буквально рухнет. Начнется разгул преступности, у людей развяжутся руки, и они пойдут грабить, насиловать, крушить. Вот мне интересно: вы и о себе так думаете? В смысле, это именно то, чего вы искренне хотите, но не можете себе позволить только из-за общественного порицания?
Сначала обобщение: всё — что, а потом конкретизация: чего именно.

В приведенном предложении сохраняем местоименную пару "то, что". Переход к чего будет подчеркнут (чего именно), а по тексту в этом нет необходимости.

Словари
Большой толковый словарь русского языка
  **ЖЕЛАТЬ,**  нсв. 1. чего (также с инф. или с 
  придат. дополнит.). Хотеть чего-л., стремиться к 
  чему-л. Ж. славы, успеха, признанья. Желаю знать 
  ваше мнение. Не желаете ли кофейку? Ж. 
  невозможного. Лучшего и ж. нельзя. Я не желаю с 
  вами разговаривать!

Управление в русском языке
  **ЖЕЛАТЬ** — 1. [**хотеть**; выражать какие-л. 
  пожелания] чего. Желать себе счастья; Желать 
  доброго пути; [Родители] желают этого брака (Т.); 
  Желаю тебе всякой удачи в твоём предприятии 
 (Перв.). 2. (при **конкретизации** объекта) кого- 
  что. Разве это та женщина, которую мать может 
  желать женой своего единственного сына? (Л. Т.); 
  Желаю именно эту книгу. 3. [выражать 
  **пожелания**] кому / для кого. Вы, должно быть, 
  мне совсем счастья не желаете! (Остр.); 
  ...Случилось всё то, что Нехлюдов мог желать для 
  Катюши

